# Redundant and Load Balanced storage on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, storage, load-balancing, redundancy

Back from:
[Load balanced & Redundant Storage on FreeBSD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81252/load-balanced-redundant-storage-on-freebsd)

How do I create a (Redundant and Load Balanced) Storage based on FreeBSD?

- Storage should be located on (2 or more servers) providing Redundancy and Load Balancing (round robin) at the same time.
- Storage needs to be accessible over network for other BSD machines as
  one folder (i.e. /storage) (NFS?).

Any solutions are welcome, except for `master-slave HAST` and `CARP`.

**Please don't post these: they are not related to this question.**

Comment: Hi @Radio, I thought we concluded there wasn't really any options for BSD, are you just asking to double check?

Comment: @slm: Just because my other question was closed as "unclear", that's it. Should be clear enough now, right? =)

Comment: Whoops, sorry I didn't scroll down far enough to see it was closed. Yup, seems clearer now.